# I want to have 10 different time moments that I have written below and i want to chose two of them. and see which happend earlier

Tags: python, list, loops, time

I want to have 10 different time moments that I have written below (6, 14, 39), (16, 4, 22), (14, 31, 3), (9, 27, 56), (17, 1, 33), (15, 10, 42), (7, 53, 47), (18, 11, 6), (8, 22, 45), (12, 32, 42) and i want to chose two of them by pressing for example # 3 and #5 and then the code will say which one of the two moments i picked happened earlier by using an if loop for example so it can check hours first then if they are the same to go to minutes and if not to go to seconds,and by using this time format print([dt.strftime('%H:%M:%S') for dt in dts]) but im not sure how to write it all up together

```
import random

n = 10
moments = []
hours_tracker = set()
for _ in range(10):
    hours = random.randint(0, 23)
    while hours in hours_tracker:
        hours = random.randint(0, 23)
    hours_tracker.add(hours)

    minutes = random.randint(0, 59)
    seconds = random.randint(0, 59)
    moments.append((hours, minutes, seconds))

sorted_moments < sorted(moments)

print(moments)
[(6, 14, 39), (16, 4, 22), (14, 31, 3), (9, 27, 56), (17, 1, 33), (15, 10, 42), (7, 53, 47), (18, 11, 6), (8, 22, 45), (12, 32, 42)]
```

Comment: What do you mean by. "...pressing for example # 3 and #5 ..."?

Comment: by that i mean something like this m=int(input("m = "))
    print(res[m])
    n=int(input("n = "))
    print(res[n])
i mean like a list and and i chose the index of the list like 0 is the first 1 is the second 3is the one after and so on

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, let's fix the way you sort `moments`:

```
moments.sort(key = lambda x: (x[0],x[1],x[2]))
```

With this line of code, the list, `moments`, will be sorted first by hours, minutes, then seconds.

However, it is unnecessary to sort by minutes and seconds because of this block in your code:

```
while hours in hours_tracker:
    hours = random.randint(0, 23)
```

This block prevents us from choosing any two times with the same hour, so if you want to keep it this way, we can just sort like this:

```
moments.sort(key = lambda x: x[0])
```

However, this means that we do not need to "check hours first then if they are the same to go to minutes and if not to go to seconds", since no two times will have the same hour.

Regardless, once we sort the list, whichever index comes first will have the earlier time:

EDIT:

```
import random

n = 10
moments = []
hours_tracker = set()
for _ in range(n):
    hours = random.randint(0, 23)
    #if you want hours to possibly repeat comment out while loop:
    while hours in hours_tracker:
        hours = random.randint(0, 23)
    hours_tracker.add(hours)

    minutes = random.randint(0, 59)
    seconds = random.randint(0, 59)
    moments.append((hours, minutes, seconds))

for i in range(len(moments)):
   print(str(i) + ": " + str(moments[i]))

print()

t1 = int(input("What first time would you like to select? "))
t2 = int(input("What second time would you like to select? "))

#CHECKING FOR HOURS
if ((moments[t1])[0] < (moments[t2])[0]):
  print(str(moments[t1]) + " occurred before " + str(moments[t2]))
elif ((moments[t1])[0] > (moments[t2])[0]):
  print(str(moments[t2]) + " occurred before " + str(moments[t1]))

#if you want to check for minutes and seconds (in case hours are the same), uncomment the rest of this block:
# CHECKING FOR MINUTES
# else:
#   if ((moments[t1])[1] < (moments[t2])[1]):
#     print(str(moments[t1]) + " occurred before " + str(moments[t2]))
#   elif ((moments[t1])[1] > (moments[t2])[1]):
#     print(str(moments[t2]) + " occurred before " + str(moments[t1]))
#   CHECKING FOR SECONDS
#   else:
#     if ((moments[t1])[2] < (moments[t2])[2]):
#       print(str(moments[t1]) + " occurred before " + str(moments[t2]))
#     elif ((moments[t1])[2] > (moments[t2])[2]):
#       print(str(moments[t2]) + " occurred before " + str(moments[t1]))
#     else:
#       print("You chose two of the same moments :P")
```

Here, we first check if the hours of `t1` are smaller than that of `t2`, and vice versa. This is all that is necessary if you choose to have hours NOT repeat.

If you want to potentially have hours repeat, remove your while loop. In this case, we need to check for minutes and seconds. In the event that the hours are the same, we then check for minutes, and then for seconds.

EDIT:

If you want the user to receive the possible options before selecting, enter these lines of code before you receive their input:

```
for i in range(len(moments)):
  print(str(i) + ": " + str(moments[i]))

print()
```

This will iterate through `moments`, output the index, and the corresponding element.

Comment: is there a way to write the list of times before im asked which one i would like to select ? because people will be chosing randomly

Comment: yea i just saw ur other comment im abt to edit answer

Comment: @KamelAwad answer edited lmk if u need anything else

Comment: well as the code is created so that the hours will not be repeating i dont think that there will be a problem to see which moment came earlier but I would like to ask how could i make that the choices of time i would like to select be visible before i chose it as it would make more sense for new users for example:{0: (18, 56,34), 1: (18, 55,29), 2: (7, 20,25), 3: (19, 36,48), 4:(7, 15,23),5: (18, 36,56),6: (2, 49,33),7: (2, 22,43), 8: (18, 33,23), 9: (17, 29,44)} chose your index and i would say 1 and 3 and the result would say You chose: 18:55:29 and 19:36:48 18:55:29 is earlier than 19:36:48

Comment: OHHHH I see what ur saying I gotchu gimme a sec

Comment: @KamelAwad just edited

Comment: May I ask how many year of experience you have ?

Comment: Hmmm I’be been programming for about 2-3ish years now

Comment: That's a lot of years hopefully I will be like you someday thank you sir not only did you answer the question you also explained how it, thank you so much

Comment: awww tysm <3 I’m sure with practice you will be an amazing coder :)

Answer (score 1):

so to choose, we can just edit the code to get the first two or get the user to choose it.

In this case we'll take from the index.

just add a line saying:

```
indexes = [3,5]
moments = [moments[index] for index in indexes]
```

to see the earliest, we'll just sort them with a key that calculates the seconds.

```
sorted_moments = sorted(moments,key=lambda x:3600*x[0]+60*x[1]+x[2])
```

but we'll take out the key because the way of how tuples are sorted makes uneccessary the expression.

so to calculate the earliest, we'll just take the first item.

```
earliest = sorted_moments[0]
```

in your case, this is the code that we'll use to calculate that.

```
>>> moments = [(6, 14, 39), (16, 4, 22), (14, 31, 3), (9, 27, 56), (17, 1, 33), (15, 10, 42), (7, 53, 47), (18, 11, 6), (8, 22, 45), (12, 32, 42)]
>>> indexes = [0,3] 
>>> sorted_moments = sorted(moments)
>>> earliest = sorted_moments[0]     
>>> earliest
(6, 14, 39)
```

Comment: this is what I wanted but it wanted it a bit differently i wanted to chose which index of the list i want like m = 0 and m = 3 in the output and it would chose (6, 14, 39) and (9, 27, 56) and then out of the chosen outputs i want an equation to calculate which happend earlier out of the 2 chosen moments

Comment: @XxJames07- The lambda expression is unnecessary due to way in which tuples are enumerated

Answer (score 1):

My interpretation of this question is that 10 different pseudo-random times should be generated. The user can then choose a value by specifying an index value (0-9). The chosen times will be shown along with an indication of relationship between those times - i.e., before or after.

If that's the case then:

```
from random import randint

N = 10
PRINT = True

def hhmmss():
    return randint(0, 23), randint(0, 59), randint(0, 59)

def format(t):
    return f'{t[0]:02d}:{t[1]:02d}:{t[2]:02d}'

tracker = set()

while len(tracker) < N:
    tracker.add(hhmmss())

tracker = list(tracker)

while True:
    try:
        if PRINT:
            for i, v in enumerate(tracker):
                print(f'{i}. {format(v)}')
            print()
        if (s1 := int(input(f'Select an index in the range 0-{N-1} (Ctrl-C to exit): '))) < 0 or s1 > N-1:
            raise ValueError('Out of range')
        if (s2 := int(input(f'Select another index in the range 0-{N-1}: '))) < 0 or s2 > N-1:
            raise ValueError('Out of range')
        if s1 == s2:
            raise ValueError('Selected values must differ')
        dt1, dt2 = tracker[s1], tracker[s2]
        print('You chose:', format(dt1), 'and', format(dt2))
        if dt1 < dt2:
            print(format(dt1), 'is earlier than', format(dt2))
        else:
            print(format(dt1), 'is later than', format(dt2))
    except ValueError as e:
        print(e)
    except KeyboardInterrupt:
        break
```

Comment: This code works perfectly but how could i add the randomized moments before to i can Select an index from the range of 0 - 9 , I would like to make it easier so people can see which indexes they can use

Comment: something like this
{0: (18, 56,34), 1: (18, 55,29), 2: (7, 20,25), 3: (19, 36,48), 4: (7, 15,23), 5: (18, 36,56), 6: (2, 49,33), 7: (2, 22,43), 8: (18, 33,23), 9: (17, 29,44)} chose your index and i would say 1 and 3 and the result would say You chose: 18:55:29 and 19:36:48
18:55:29 is earlier than 19:36:48

Comment: @KamelAwad Answer edited